# Camera Calibration Uses Wrong Aspect Ratio from USB Camera

Tags: calibration, camera, image-pipeline, usb-cam, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to calibrate a USB camera running at 1080p (i.e., 1920x1080). When launching `usb_cam` and then `image_view`, the image comes up correctly at the right aspect ration.

`rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node _image_width:=1920 _image_height:=1080 _pixel_format:=yuyv`
`rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw`

[image: image description]

However, whenever we try and run the camera calibration node, the aspect ratio of the image seems to be reversed:

`rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.025 image:=/usb_cam/image_raw camera:=/usb_cam`

[image: image description]

We are running Ubuntu 14.04 64bit with the latest Indigo build.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190725/camera-calibration-uses-wrong-aspect-ratio-from-usb-camera/) by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1173 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) on 2014-08-21**:
Created a ticket/pull request here for a possible bug:

https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/pull/94

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fixed with https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/pull/94

---

Originally posted by [rtoris288](https://answers.ros.org/users/982/rtoris288/) with karma: 1173 on 2015-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0